# Custom Asynchronous function in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

```
console.log('Start');
const myFunc = async () => {
 for(let i=0; i<10000000000000; i++){}
 console.log('After for loop');
}
myFunc();
console.log('end');
```

I want async behaviour using async/await. I want my function to pass the entire function to an event loop same as SetTimeout, SetInterval does so that my main thread can continue to do the rest unless that heavy functionality is running behind the scene.

**Expected Output: Start, end, After for loop**

**Current Output: Start, AFter for loop, end**

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous in `myFunc`. Everything is synchronous. Something that takes a long time isn’t automatically asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of *asynchronous* javascript code is not correct.

Function passed to `setTimeout` doesn't execute in the *background* - it executes on the *main* thread and while that function is executing, nothing else executes.

It's just that the callback function of `setTimeout` is pushed in to the call stack *after* the timer has expired and the call stack is empty. This is why other code can execute *before* the callback function of `setTimeout` executes.

Some functions provided by the browser such as HTTP requests happen in the background and once they are complete, Javascript will invoke our callback function and once that callback function starts executing, it blocks everything else from executing until that function is popped off the call stack.

Putting your code inside an `async` function doesn't makes your code *asynchronous*; it will execute synchronously until the first *await* expression. *(Promises do not make anything asynchronous. They are just a notification mechanism that notifies you of either successful completion or a failure of something that is **already** asynchronous.)*

What you need is another thread that executes the long running code without blocking the main thread. You can do this using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) in the browser or [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) in NodeJS.

Comment: If this is in node.js you'd similarly want to look at [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads)

Comment: @AlienWithPizza Thank you for the comment. I didn't notice that the question was tagged with `nodejs`